# PHP PDO Insert problem

Tags: php, mysql, database

I've hit a wall with a PDO insert:

```
$q = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO grant (grant_name, update) VALUES (?,?)');
$q->bindParam(1, $grant_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$q->bindParam(2, $update, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$q->execute();
```

I get an error:

```
 PHP Warning:  PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;
```

But I cannot find the problem. I have tried using placeholder (such as :grant_name) and using the question marks (?).

Comment: Not sure, but isn't "update" a reserved word? Try putting `update` in backticks.

Comment: It fails even with a single field, such as `$grant_name.`

Comment: That's because `GRANT` is a reserved word as well!

Comment: @Brad: haha, d'oh, I completely missed that!

Answer (score 6):

Both `GRANT` and `UPDATE` have specific meanings in SQL.  Try this:

```
$q = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO `grant` (`grant_name`, `update`) VALUES (?,?)');
```

Answer (score 1):

Having a column name of `UPDATE` would appear to be your problem.  Try quoting the column name (or changing the column name to something that's not a reserved word).